# Can't Understand this simple code output

Tags: c

Code:

```
int a = 5;
int *ptr;
ptr = &a;

printf("%d",*ptr);
printf("\n%d",*(ptr++));
printf("\n%d",(*ptr)++);
printf("\n%d",++(*ptr));
```

Output:

```
5
5
1638268
1638268
```

and I am expecting the output to be:
    5
    junk
    5
    7
Sory, my pointer and operator precedence concept is very bleak. Can't understand this simple ouput.

Comment: try change the `++` by `+=1`

Comment: @fotanus and that would make a difference because...?

Comment: @Juhana because ++ is pos increment, and +=1 do not increment the pointer,  just yields a new value, thus do not change the ptr value

Comment: @fotanus I'm pretty sure that's not how it works.

Comment: I make a deliberate point of not understanding these precedence rules, I just write the code out in a way that a newbie programmer who may have to maintain my code one day will understand. If you're trying to maintain code that looks like this, first understand its intention then re-write it so the tests still pass. You have tests, right?

Comment: @Juhana, I'm sorry, I mean +1, not += 1 :p

Comment: @fotanus What if the OP is doing some exercise on how pointers and increments mix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The first is obviously 5, just dereferencing a pointer
2. Still five because the postfix operator returns the pointer preincrement
3. 3 and 4 are junk because the pointer no longer points to memory that has been assigned

If you want the second to act like you expected and print junk you can use the prefix `++` instead

Answer (score 4):

```
int a = 5;
int *ptr;
ptr = &a;

printf("%d",*ptr);          // 5 as you expected.
printf("\n%d",*(ptr++));    // 5, because the pointer is incremented after this line
printf("\n%d",(*ptr)++);    // Not 5 because pointer points to another location.
printf("\n%d",++(*ptr));    // Pointer already changed, no longer pointing at 5.
```

Comment: Any particular reason for `%` comments instead of `//`?

Comment: @Riley my silly mistake. I was working on MATLAB. I corrected it. Thanks for bring that up.

Comment: generally I do not it here as this is the answer So I think make it visible :)

Answer (score 3):

```
int a = 5;
int *ptr; 
ptr = &a;  // ptr is the address of the int 5

printf("%d",*ptr);  // dereferences ptr, which points to in 5
printf("\n%d",*(ptr++));  // increments ptr by one, so ptr not points to 
                          // an int one over from wherever int 5 is in memory
                          // but return ptr before incrementing and then dereference it
                          // giving int 5
printf("\n%d",(*ptr)++);  // dereference ptr, which is now one int over from 5 thanks
                          // to the last line, which is garbage, try 
                          // to increment garbage by 1 after printing
printf("\n%d",++(*ptr));  // dereference ptr, which is now one int over from 5, 
                          // try to increment garbage by one before printing
```

Answer (score 3):

`*ptr` just gives the value at the location which is nothing but value of `a`.

`*(ptr++)` is equivalent to `(*ptr)` and then `(ptr += 1)` because of **post** increment, so first it gives the value which is used by printf and then increments the pointer so now it is pointing to junk memory .

`(*ptr)++` is equivalent to `(*ptr)` and then `(*ptr += 1)`, so it takes the value at junk memory and increments it.

`++(*ptr)` is equivalent to `(*ptr) += 1` so it increments the value at the junk location, now you can see  the effect of  `undefined behavior` so you don't get the last incremented value plus one, but got the same value as the last one because of undefined behavior. On my compiler I got the last incremented value plus one.